# Django: forms.ModelChoiceField based on pk of calling view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I'm looking for a way to filter contents of a `forms.ModelChoiceField()` by the `pk` of a calling view.

I have a class based view:

```
class StorageItemMergeView(FormView):
    form_class = MergeStorageItemsForm
    #....
```

which is using `MergeStorageItemsForm`, currently defined as:

```
class MergeStorageItemsForm(forms.Form):
    storageitem1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StorageItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"]))
```

StorageItemMergeView is connected to an object, so I only want to offer objects, which are also connected. I tried to put kwargs to form definition in several variations as e.g.

```
storageitem1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StorageItem.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs["pk"]))
```

kwargs seems not to be defined in this context.

Also I found, that found that it is possible to redefine `__init__()` on a modelForm to get something like that done

```
def __init__(self, user=None, **kwargs):
    super(MergeStorageItemsForm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    #...
```

This didn't do the trick. How is it possible to filter the options offered by a form based on request and/or object the corresponding view is called for?

My corresponding section of urls.py look like that

```
url(r'^storageitem/(?P<pk>[\w]+)/merge/$', login_required(
        StorageItemMergeView.as_view()), name='storage_item_merge'),
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do that in `__init__` method, like this:

```
class MergeStorageItemsForm(forms.Form):
    storageitem1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=StorageItem.objects.none())

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.storage_pk = kwargs.pop('pk')
        super(MergeStorageItemsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fileds['storageitem1'].queryset = StorageItem.objects.get(pk=self.storage_pk)
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need to pimp something else. It's not finding 'pk' in line ` self.storage_pk = kwargs.pop('pk')`.

Comment: When creating an instance of form pass the `pk` as key word parameter like this `form = MergeStorageItemsForm(pk=1)`

Comment: Hmmm still stuck. But now at the point, that I don't have pk at the point. Did had a look onto dispatch() and get_context_data() but not to get it running. Inside e.g. form_valid() there is some ... hmmm